# Testing null byte vulnerability

Tags: php, security

I am helping my friend to finish his module for a website. From my first impression looking at his modules, I found some very dangerous things, but he says that this method is secure.

Part of the code :

```
session_start();

  if(isset($_POST['foo'])) 
  {
    $_SESSION['foo'] = $_POST['foo'];
  }

  if(isset($_SESSION['foo']))
  {
    $foo['foo']  = $_SESSION['foo'];
  }

  if(is_file("inc/". $foo['foo'] . "/bar.php")) {
    // code
  }
  else {
    // code
  }
```

Note : file (inc/test/bar.php) exists;

I wanted to test his code, and I sent the following requests :

**POST :: foo => test/bar.php%00**

**POST :: foo => test/bar.php\0**

**curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'foo=test/bar.php' . chr(0x00));**

But none of these methods worked. Is that code really secure? and how could someone send a null byte to bypass it's security. I want to demonstrate to my friend that his code is not secure.

Comment: I'm not a php expert so I'll leave this as a comment, but couldn't you pass something like "../../../../" and gain arbitrary access to the file system?

Comment: @ChrisThompson it has "/bar.php" at the end so it will check ../../../bar.php in all cases

Comment: right ok so it's only a threat if you're potentially accessing _some other_ `bar.php` file that you're not supposed to access

Comment: @ChrisThompson, yes, but will this script be vulnerable to null byte injection? i mean something like "../../protectedFile.php%00/bar.php"

Comment: I'm not sure :-), like I said, not a php expert.  Strikes me like a bad idea to pass unsanitized user input any time.  Based on the cursory research I did it's system dependent.  So it may be secure on one system but not on another based on whether it uses null-terminated strings.  Check out http://hakipedia.com/index.php/Poison_Null_Byte

Comment: PHP 5.3.4 and later have solved the problem ([release notes](http://php.net/releases/5_3_4.php)). Only earlier versions are vulnerable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found [this](http://www.hackthis.co.uk/articles/common-php-attacks-poison-null-byte) solution, in short, it seems your code **is** somewhat vulnerable, and the sanitizing method is this:

> There are a number of ways to prevent Poison Null Byte injections within PHP. These include escaping the NULL byte with a backslash, however, the most recommended way to do so is to completely remove the byte by using code similar to the following:

```
$foo['foo']= str_replace(chr(0), '', $foo['foo']);
```

I'm also not an expert in null-byte attacks, but this makes sense. 
Even more details [here](http://hakipedia.com/index.php/Poison_Null_Byte).

Comment: The OP should even replace the null-byte character when saving the value from `$_POST` into the session! That prevents a possible later and unsafe reuse of `$_SESSION['foo']`.

Answer (score -2):

Php is very vurnable for Null bytes.... because php is build on c.
In c a Null byte means end of string.

You should remove Null bytes on every string you use..
This is even more important on IO based functions like include en move_uploaded_file.

Even (int)"1\01" is vurnable because it casts to int 1

Php functions that can handle Null bytes are for example

str_replace
strpos
strlen

Even on database querys. Mysql is vurnable to for Null bytes on char, varchar and text columns

Comment: This is no longer true for PHP 5.3.4 and later. (Which is all current versions.)

Comment: Actually, a bunch of the followup stuff here is just false. PHP's string handling functions (like `strlen()`) work perfectly fine on strings including null bytes, as does MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for -1 go on even php 5.4 the include function will break up with a Null byte and run SELECT "hello\0there" then you will see..

Comment: Look closer. `include()` will always fail on filenames which include a null byte (rather than truncating at the null byte), and running a `SELECT` which contains a null byte will return the null byte unmolested.