# How can I remove null byte in my Query String URLs with Php?

Tags: php, null, byte, query-string, str-replace

I'd like to know how I can remove the null byte (\0) in my URLs. I know that from Php 5.3.4 this security hole has been fixed but maybe something can be passed from malicious users on other servers running php 5.3 or less. This can happen using query strings, I would like to understand how to protect my URLs to release my scripts without security implications regarding this bug.

Example: http://www.example.com/download.php?text=\0

I have two hypothesis:

A) `$text = str_replace("\0", "", $text);`

B) `$text = str_replace('\0', '', $text);`

What version is safe and correct? A or B? Thanks.

PS: I'm running php 5.6.17 on CentOS... with Apache 2.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is nothing to do with security, but with the way in which strings are treated in php:

- **double quoted strings are evaluated**
- **single quoted strings are not evaluated**

`\` is an escape character, so the following character is escaped.

To match it in a double quoted string, you have to prepend an additional backslash: `\\0`

#### Edit:

You say “Null byte removing in php”, and then “while if I put $text = str_replace('\0', '', $text); the \0 will be removed”.

This means that in your string **there is not a null byte**, but a backslash followed by a zero (≈ a *rapresentation* of Null byte).

Examples:

```
echo strlen( 'http://www.example.com/download.php?text=' );     // output: 41
echo strlen( "http://www.example.com/download.php?text=\0" );   // output: 42 (Null)
echo strlen( 'http://www.example.com/download.php?text=\0' );   // output: 43

echo strlen( '\0' );                                            // output: 2
echo strlen( "\0" );                                            // output: 1  (Null)
```

And  also:

```
echo strlen(trim( "http://www.example.com/download.php?text=\0" ));
```

will output, **41**, because `trim` removes Null byte

```
echo strlen(trim( 'http://www.example.com/download.php?text=\0' ));
```

will output, **43**, because `trim` doesn't remove the `\0`

Comment: Like this? `$text = str_replace("\\0", "", $text);` but so that is actually a byte null? `\\0` Thanks! I want match byte null with str_replace and remove it from the string...

Comment: @Alessandro You say that in title question, but in example provided you say that the replacement succeed if you use single quote, so in your string there is not a NULL, but a backslash followed by a zero. Try yourself: `echo (strlen ("\0")); echo (strlen ('\0'));`  The len of string in single quoted character is 2

Comment: So You say that `\0` is not a null byte? `$text = str_replace('\0', '', $text);` is not matching a null byte? While using `$text = str_replace("\0", "", $text);` is matching a null byte? Tell me if I wrong... please and thanks...

Comment: Yes, exactly! backslash in single quoted is not evaluated

Comment: `\0` is a byte nul, but not in the string you have evaluated (if so, you can't see it: is null)

Comment: So I'm a bit confused... `$text = str_replace("\0", "", $text);` is matching a null byte even if I cannot see it? So You should suggest me `$text = str_replace("\0", "", $text);` to prevent a null byte attack?

Comment: I'm not expert in any attack question, but yes, to replace null values you have to use `str_replace("\0", "", $text)`

Comment: I just edited my question so now it's a bit more clear... null byte are used to perform an attack. I'd like to clean input in the url without using trim but str_replace. Common modern attacks are performed with byte null... http://hakipedia.com/index.php/Poison_Null_Byte

Comment: @Alessandro see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16366322/testing-null-byte-vulnerability) about “the most recommended way to prevent Poison Null Byte injections”.

Comment: Thanks @fusion3k I already read this discussion. I think, but I can mistake, that `$text = str_replace("\0", "", $text);` and `$text = str_replace(chr(0), '', $text);` are equivalents at this point... Tell me if I'm wrong....

Comment: Yes, they are equivalents

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to solve this particular problem is to use the `chr()` function:

```
$text = str_replace(chr(0), '', $text);
```

Comment: Thanks, very appreciated.